# UITextView is not displayed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I create a contact form and therefore I use a UITextView in my storyboard but when I launch the application, my UITextView is not displayed ...: /

Someone would have the solution to this bug? The only tool I can give you is a screenshot because there is almost no code.

Thank you in advance for your help ! And especially Happy New Year everyone!

[Explications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKQ8P.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `UITextView` doesn’t know its **height**.

You have to set its bottom constraint or height constraint (in this case bottom constraint equal to *Emvoyer* button’s top constraint seems correct).